# Gitlab Group is not visible for shairing the Project

Tags: gitlab

Looks like something has changed in GitLab as I am not able to see my Groups for sharing the Private Projects even if the owner of the Project and the Group are same/myself.

It was working before couple of month as I was able to do above without any issues but not now.

Example:
1) I have created a Group (Ex: V5Contributors) in GitLab with Visibility Level as "Private" and the Group Path is under "https://gitlab.com/".
2) I have created a "Private" Project "MyProj" under "https://gitlab.com/" Project Path.
3) Then I select the Project and go to "Groups" under "Settings" to share the project with the Group members but I can't search/find the group that I created.

Could someone advise what is wrong in my process? I just want to have a Group with several users and share some of our projects with the Group instead of each members.

Comment: Hi, did you get an answer/solution for this? I'm struggling to share a project with a group too. Trying to follow https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/share_projects_with_other_groups.html#sharing-a-project-with-a-group-of-users doesn't work; the option doesn't appear on the menu.

Comment: @9swampy New version of GitLab has the solution and it works as expected. We can grant permission on our projects to our Private Groups.

Comment: From memory we're on 8.4.4. Do you know what version introduced the solution?